# Java Dynamic Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have two classes: gui and class with variables such as tab[][] . I want to do my JTable dynamic, i have to use TableModelListner , but i don't know what should i do that my table will be update for example:

tab[1][0] i change in GUI and the value of tab[1][1],tab[1][2],tab[1][3] will be new.

```
table = new JTable(classone.tab,columnsN);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,150));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane);
```

Comment: `Java Dynamic Jtable` haven't something with `TableModelListner`, XxxTableModel is responsible to hold and notify any changes, TableModelListener firing only part of those events

Comment: tour question is not clear. especially elaborate this part: `tab[1][0] i change in GUI and the value of tab[1][1],tab[1][2],tab[1][3] will be new`

Answer (score 1):

> i have two classes: gui and class with variables such as tab[][]

Once you create the JTable you should NEVER reference tab[][] again. The array will be used to create a `DefaultTableModel`. If you want to make dynamic changes you MUST change the TableModel.

To add new rows of data you can use

```
model.addRow(...);
model.insertRow(....);
model.removeRow(...);
```

Read the DefaultTableModel API for other methods.

To change existing data you would use:

```
table.setValueAt(...);
```

Comment: ![Screen gui][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eyMct.png


I edit value in first row for example 100 to 140 and the rest value should change because they depend on value , which was edited. What should i do?

Comment: Write you TableModelListener and then use the setValueAt() method as required. Or override the setVAlueAt(..) method of the TableModel and update the data as required.